# Can I use $A.createComponent() in the controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I know that Lightning Components may not modify the DOM in the controller in order to pass the Appexchange Security Review. I need to create a new component with $A.createComponent() and I can't invoke this in my component's renderer.

The lightning developer guide has an example where $A.createComponent() is invoked in the controller and I want to know if this will satisfy the no DOM modification in the controller requirement, since rendering occurs when a component is created.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Carlos. Its unclear to me what your real question is here. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then use the edit link at the bottom left of your post to clarify what it is that your asking.

Comment: I thought the question was clear, and edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. The rendering in the component you created is happening in that component's renderer, not in your controller.